# Generating uniform random numbers between two large integers in fortran90/95 or Python

Tags: python, random, fortran, montecarlo

I want to generate some uniform random numbers between [2E16, 5E20] in fortran90/95 or Python. I know that if "R" is a random number between zero and one (0<R<1), we can transform R to [A, B] as:

R = (b-a)*r + a.

But when I use this algorithm to generate some random numbers between [2E16, 5E20], most of generated random numbers are very close to 5E20. I know why this is occurred, it is because of that, the term B-A is approximately equal to B (because B is so bigger than A), and most of the generated random numbers are placed within the magnitude of B or B/10 (I mean it was very close to B).

How can I solve this problem?

One solution that I tried to apply is that, I split the [2E16, 5E20] interval into smaller intervals, such as:

[2e16, 2e17], [2e17, 2e18], [2e18, 2e19], [2e19, 2e20], [2e20, 5e20].

And I generated some random numbers between each of the above intervals.

Is there any other solutions? Is my solution correct?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Your question is very confusing. It seems you do not actually want a uniform distribution but some logarithmic distribution.

Comment: Further to Vladimir's comment about logarithmic distributions, there simply are more integers between 1e19 and 1e20 than there are between 1e18 and 1e19.  Ten times more.

Comment: If you want every integer in the range to have an equal chance of showing up, and you're willing to use python, what's wrong with `random.randint(20000000000000000, 500000000000000000000)`?

Answer (score 1):

This is less of a programming problem, and more of a maths problem.

You need to think about which distribution you are drawing your random numbers from. Any [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution) which spans several orders of magnitude will always produce more numbers with larger exponents than with smaller exponents.

If you want a distribution which produces the same number of numbers with each exponent, you should consider the [log uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_distribution), which can be sampled using e.g. [scipy.stats.loguniform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.loguniform.html).